# Generate data matrix using the given data matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

Suppose I have a `200 x 200` matrix using the following `r` function.

```
n = 200
sim.mat = matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = n)
 for (i in 1:n){
   sim.mat[,i] = c(rnorm(i, 2, 1), rnorm(n-i, 3, 1))
 }
```

How can I generate `200 x 1000`matrix using the same `c(rnorm(i, 2, 1), rnorm(n-i, 3, 1))` setting?

Thank you.

Comment: By your definition, you cannot: if you draw `i` with mean 2 and `n-i` with mean 3 for each column, what happens at column 201 when `n-i < 0`?

Comment: @r2evans, am I able to replicate the `200x200` matrix to generate `200x1000` matrix?

Comment: That's different. `do.call(cbind, replicate(5, sim.mat, simplify=FALSE))` will repeat the same matrix 5 times, side-by-side, into one 200x1000 matrix.